Animated story of space explorers held captive by aliens to play sports
I recall watching an animated story in the mid 1980s as a kid where explorers go to either the moon or another planet and encounter an alien race that can jump high or far. The aliens end up forcing the people to stay and play sports and games. Eventually the people do escape. I recall it had a very Trip to the Moon kind of feel to it but that could just be my 40 year old memories failing me. This was likely a short animated film, it was not a full feature length movie nor was it a series.

This reminds me so much of a book about a football (soccer) team who were incredibly, record-breakingly bad - so much so that an alien football team abducted them and took them back to their home planet just to be able to win against someone! Unfortunately, in low alien gravity, the Worst Team turned out to be hot stuff and kept beating them. The aliens refused to let them go home until they lost a game. I CANNOT find this by googling though!
